# RandomAccessFile adding ETX M to start of file

Tags: java, file-io

This is on CentOS 6.2. I am writing to a text file, and it is adding a ETX M to the beggining. (ETX is the name of the character)

```
file.setLength(0);
file.seek(0);
file.writeUTF(somestring);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for `RandomAccessile.writeUTF()`

> First, two bytes are written to the file, starting at the current file pointer, as if by the writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the string. Following the length, each character of the string is output, in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for each character.

If you don't want this, convert the string to bytes manually and write those bytes with the basic `write()` method (nb: `writeBytes()` *is not* what you want). However, you're going to need some way to keep track of the size of the string in order to read it again (unless you're using fixed-width fields).